# Credit card stopped due to fraud activity, but hotel booking needs credit card for security bond

Tags: payment-cards

So I'll be checking in a apartment hotel tomorrow, my company booked the hotel with the company credit card, but I realize that during check in they require a credit card for security bond. And the hotel stated on their website that no cash payment is accepted.

My card got stopped yesterday by the bank due to a suspicious fraud, and new card is still on its way via mail. So I don't have a valid credit card to use, and they do not accept cash. So I have no idea what I need to do, called them just now but reception opens tomorrow morning, and I'm quite worried. Can they cancel my stay if I don't have a valid credit card for the security bond? I do have a Debit MasterCard but that's different from a credit card.

Comment: If your stay is paid and you seem like a reasonable guest, the hotel wants you to stay, and will work with you to make things work. Cancelling your stay is against their interests.

Comment: Debit card should be fine, if you have sufficient funds available for the hold to be honoured.

Comment: This is an example of why one should always have multiple credit cards when traveling.

Answer (score 4):

The hotel will want to take an authorisation hold on some of the money available on the card to cover any incidental costs/damages done.

A Debit Mastercard operates in the Mastercard card scheme so you might have some luck in having the hotel process a hold on it. If a hold is processed, some of the money in the attached transaction account will be inaccessible until the hold expires, which may be after your stay.

You might be able to try for an emergency replacement card for your other card. Depending on factors such as the card scheme, issuer and country you're in, you might be able to get it quicker than five days. My bank says they can do it in two business days.